# How to change default code in Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am going to programming c++ with Visual Studio, but there is something annoying and that's the default code, which is shown automatically in launching the editor. Is there a way to change that or it is rigid ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is: you can create a Visual Studio project template and use that as the basis for future projects.  The way you do this is to get your project looking how you like it and then save it as a template.  Full details here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019