# Visual Studio - C++ New File Default Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Hey everyone I have a comfort problem is Visual Studio 2017 (I use 2017 because of school requirement).
Always when I start a new C++ Project or C++ File I get the default code:

```
// ConsoleApplication4.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}

// Run program: Ctrl + F5 or Debug > Start Without Debugging menu
// Debug program: F5 or Debug > Start Debugging menu

// Tips for Getting Started: 
//   1. Use the Solution Explorer window to add/manage files
//   2. Use the Team Explorer window to connect to source control
//   3. Use the Output window to see build output and other messages
//   4. Use the Error List window to view errors
//   5. Go to Project > Add New Item to create new code files, or Project > Add Existing Item to add existing code files to the project
//   6. In the future, to open this project again, go to File > Open > Project and select the .sln file
```

It's very annoying for me to delete it every time and I'll be happy to know how to remove the default code. I searched the Internet and Microsoft MSDN and I didn't find any solution. Thank you for your help, this website helps me a lot!

Comment: Is the MSDN page relevant? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-update-existing-templates?view=vs-2019#:~:text=Choose%20File%20%3E%20New%20%3E%20Project%20from,new%20file%20to%20the%20project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default code in Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61555685/how-to-change-default-code-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to create a empty project.

1.1 Create a project.

1.2 Edit the project until it is ready to be exported as a template. For example, you might want to edit code files to indicate where parameter replacement should take place. See How to: Substitute parameters in a template.

1.3 On the `Project` menu, choose `Export Template`.

The Export `Template Wizard` opens.

1.4 On the Choose Template Type page, select `Project Template`. Select the project you want to export to a template, and then choose `Next`.

1.5 On the Select Template Options page, enter a name and optional description, icon, and preview image for your template. These items will appear in the dialog box where you create a new project. Choose `Finish`.

2. You could use `Windows Desktop Wizard`.

[image]

Then select `Empty Project`.

[image]