# Is there a way to create a default template for includes, libraries etc for visual studio 2019? (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I would like to eliminate the hassle of including the same libraries in every project. Is there a way that I can make a template for new projects which includes certain libraries in visual studio 2019, or perhaps some way I can include these libraries globally so that they can be included like the standard library? If not, why is this behavior undesirable? thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61555785

Comment: yes it does, thank you! @PaulSanders

Answer (score 0):

ANother solution (I believe only applicable if you use msbuild rather than cmake) is to edit the default platform property sheet.

These are found via the View -> Other Windows -> Property Manager menu item (requires having an msbuild-based project open).

Open the project node then one of the build configuration nodes, right click on Microsoft.Cpp..user and select Properties (I am blind so don't use a mouse, double clicking the node may also work, not sure about that) and edit it like any property sheet. The imported property sheets are actually how default properties like the libraries and include paths are generated, although digging through them all can quickly become a mess.