# how can i set specifically c++17 on vs community 22?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, visual-studio-2022

I have to learn specifically the cpp17 and we will use that.
And I don't  have any clue how to set specifically that version.

I was trying to change the c++ settings in tools but I didn't find anything like this.

Comment: You change it per project/solution. To do this you should open project properties (right mouse click on the solution tree) and go to: `C/C++ -> Language -> C++ Language Standard`

Comment: I feel like this has to be documented online already.

Comment: One you have the settings as you like them, you can create a template for future projects, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61555685/how-to-change-default-code-in-visual-studio/61555785#61555785

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170

Comment: Did the answer below work for you? Note : the settings in debug and release are independent. You need to set C++17 for them respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following. Go to project property page

[image]

After you enter the property page, you should be able to choose standard version in `C/C++ -> Language -> C++ Language Standard`.

[image]